# AspxClientTreeList ContextMenu "e.htmlEvent.y" different value with different Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I used *AspxTreeList* control of DevExpress.

In the client side, I used `ContextMenu` Event.

I retrieve `e.htmlEvent.y` value for right click.

The problem is that in IE8, the value is different than IE11. Why?

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the client-side **ASPxClientUtils.GetEventX** / **ASPxClientUtils.GetEventY** methods to retrieve the correct values:

```
var x = ASPxClientUtils.GetEventX(e.htmlEvent);
var y = ASPxClientUtils.GetEventY(e.htmlEvent);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to my problem.

I check the version of IE.

```
function isIE () {
 var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
 return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
}

if (isIE () == 8) {
  // IE8 code
} else {
  // Other versions IE or not IE
}
```